# Como implemento NgModule en un campo personalizado

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Estoy implementando el siguiente componente personalizado para subir archivos:

[image: captura de pantalla del componente]

Necesito saber como puedo asociarle un `NgModel` al componente personalizado que cree, para poder manejarlo mas fácilmente y almacenar la ruta del archivo que se subió para poder acceder a la misma como un atributo como si fuese un `<input>` normal.

Dejo el codigo del componento que tengo hasta el momento.

file-input.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'file-input',
    templateUrl: './file-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./file-input.scss']
})
export class FileInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() codSubproyecto: string;
    public subproyecto: any;
    public subproyecto$: Subscription;
    public filePath: string;
    public fileName: string;


    constructor(
        private multimediaService: MultimediaService,
        private subProyectosService: SubProyectosService
    ) {
        this.fileName = '';
        this.filePath = '';
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.subproyecto$ = this.subProyectosService.getByCodigo(this.codSubproyecto).subscribe(_subproyecto => {
            this.subproyecto = _subproyecto;
        });
    }


    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.subproyecto$) {
            this.subproyecto$.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    public onFileChange($event) {
        if ($event.target.files.length === 1) {
            let file = $event.target.files[0];
            this.fileName = file.name;
            let data = {
                codProyecto: this.subproyecto.CodProyecto,
                codSubproyecto: this.codSubproyecto,
                codFase: 'COD_VIABILIDAD',
            };
            this.blockUI.start('subiendo archivo...');
            this.multimediaService.uploadFileHandle(data, file).subscribe(response => {
                this.filePath = response.FileUri;
                console.log(response.FileUri);
                this.blockUI.stop();
            },
            error => {
                this.filePath = '';
                console.error(error);
            });

        } else {
            this.fileName = '';
            this.filePath = '';
        }
    }
}
```

file-input.component.html

```
<div>
    <md-input-container class="input-file">
        <input mdInput [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="fileName" [disabled]="true">
    </md-input-container>
    <button 
            type="button"
            (click)="fileInforme.click()"
            class="file-button" 
            md-mini-fab>
        <md-icon>cloud_upload</md-icon>
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-check icon-green fa-lg" style="padding-left: 10px" *ngIf="filePath.length > 0"></i>            
    <input #fileInforme type="file" style="display: None;" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
</div>

<block-ui></block-ui>
```